# Count total items inserted from array into mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, count

I have a an array of urls that fetch some data which gets inserted into a db. I'm using php and pdo. I need to see how many were inserted from the entire array once it has completed, currently I have:

```
(array(
'http://www.example.com/1',
'http://www.example.com/2',
'http://www.example.com/3'))

foreach ($line->get_items() as $item){
pdo insert here...
$count = $q->rowCount();
print("Added $count Items.\n");
}
```

As expected this is returning the count for each time it is inserted, so I might get:
    Added 1 Items Added 1 Items Added 1 Items

How can I aggregate all the inserts together to see how many in total were inserted?

Comment: create a counter before/outside the loop - `$count = 0`. if the insert was successful, then increase the counter - `$count++`. then print after/outside the loop.

Comment: @Sean perfect thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you got an answer from Sean but I just wanted to show you one other way to do what you want using only one SQL query. The INSERT command supports inserting more than one row at a time.

The syntax looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name
    (a,b,c)
VALUES
    (1,2,3),
    (4,5,6),
    (7,8,9);
```

So in your case, you could just add the other rows to an array and then add them all to the query. The $count will include all the rows that were inserted.

```
<?php


$inserts = array();
foreach ($line->get_items() as $item){
    $inserts[] = "({$item['col1']},{$item['col2']})";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO items(col1,col2) VALUES " . implode(",", $inserts);
//pdo insert here...

$count = $q->rowCount();
print("Added $count Items.\n");
```

This should be slightly more efficient than using a bunch of queries.

Comment: Interesting I'll check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use a counter and add +1 to it after each pdo insert, your code will be

```
(array(
'http://www.example.com/1',
'http://www.example.com/2',
'http://www.example.com/3'))
$c = 0;
foreach ($line->get_items() as $item){
pdo insert here...
$count = $q->rowCount();
$c++; //or $c = $c +1 ;
}
Echo $c ;
```